# Page Break ASP.NET files

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm currently trying to paginate a list of records, however; after the last table, the page break leaves an empty page.  The set up is an Aspx files that incorporates two ascx files to draw the table records.

```
    <%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Table.ascx.cs" Inherits="%>

    <br class="clear" /><br/>
        <table class="report-table" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
            <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSource='<%# Eval("PatientBills") %>' OnItemDataBound="Repeater1_OnItemDataBound">
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Seq</td>
                        <td>Billing Id</td>
                        <td>Patient Id</td>
                        <td>Patient Name</td>
                        <td>Sex</td>
                        <td class="PrintNormalWrap">Admit Date</td>
                        <td class="PrintNormalWrap" style="width: 80px;">Social Security</td>
                        <td>DOB</td>
                        <td>POS</td>
                        <td>CPT</td>
                        <td>Mods</td>
                        <td style="width: 220px;">Diagnosis</td>
                        <td class="PrintNormalWrap">Referring Provider(UPIN)/ Comment</td>
                    </tr>
                </HeaderTemplate>

                <ItemTemplate>
                    <tr   class="billRowShade<%# Container.ItemIndex % 2 %>">
                        <asp:TableCell ID="tableCellSequence" runat="server"><%# Container.ItemIndex + 1 %></asp:TableCell>
                        <td><%# FormatBillingId(Eval("Bill.BillingId"))  %></td>
                        <td><%# FormatField(Eval("Patient.PatientId")) %></td>
                        <td id="printPatientName"><%# FormatField(Eval("Patient.LastName")) %>, <%# FormatField(Eval("Patient.FirstName")) %></td>
                        <td><%# FormatField(Eval("Patient.Sex")) %></td>
                        <td><%# FormatShortDate(Eval("Patient.DateOfAdmittance"))%></td>
                        <td><%# FormatField(Eval("Patient.SocialSecurityNumber")) %></td>
                        <td><%# FormatShortDate(Eval("Patient.DateOfBirth"))%></td>
                        <td><%# FormatField(Eval("Bill.Pos")) %></td>
                        <td><%# FormatField(Eval("Bill.CptCode"))    %></td>
                        <td><%# FormatField(Eval("Bill.Mod"))   %></td>
                        <td><%# FormatDiagnoses(Eval("Bill.Diagnoses"), Eval("Bill.BillDate"), Eval("Bill.SiteName")) %></td>
                        <td class="PrintNormalWrap"><%# FormatNotes(Eval("Patient.ReferringMd"), Eval("Patient.RefUpin"), Eval("Bill.Notes"), Eval("Bill.TimeEntry")) %>&nbsp;<%# FormatSupervisor( Eval("Bill.SupervisedByName"), Eval("Bill.DoctorName") ) %></td>
                    </tr>

                   <asp:TableRow ID="tableRowSpecialtyFieldDetails" runat="server" CssClass="specialtyFieldDetails">
                        <asp:TableCell ID="TableCell1" colspan="12" runat="server"><span id="spanSpecialtyFieldDetails" runat="server"></span></asp:TableCell>
                    </asp:TableRow>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
         </table>
<p style="page-break-after:always"></p>
         <br/>
```

Comment: It looks like the <p> tag is causing the page break. Do you need this for something?

Comment: I want to page break the tables, but stop the last page break from causing a blank page